# High output voltage or sink?

Tags: current-sink

As I recently learned, LED driver output voltage stands for what the pin can handle after the last cathode of LED strip. However, I am interested in this chip HV5812, that is a high voltage shift register. Do I understand correctly, that the voltage output it will provide on output pins is Vpp that I supply to it? Or are the pins working like a sink?

Datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005629A.pdf

Comment: `what the pin can handle after the last cathode of LED strip` ... what does that even mean?

Comment: As I understood, a LED driver IC with output voltage of 20V can handle 20V applied to that output pin.

Comment: look at figure 3-1

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355095/stp16cp05mtr-output-voltage/355098#355098

Comment: `LED driver IC with output voltage of 20V can handle 20V applied to that output pin` .... I would not bet on it

Comment: I do see MOSFETs in figure 3-1, but I am not strong in analog electronics. An explanation of how that circuitry works would be amazing

Comment: think of the mosfets as push button switches ... press one or the other, but not both ...

Answer (score 1):

Let's check the datasheet:

> High-level Output VOH on HVOUT min. 78V for IOUT = –25 mA, VPP = 80V

So, if the output is high, and your load uses Iout=25mA, the output voltage will not be exactly VPP=80V but around 2 volts less. So it is suitable for driving a long string of LEDs at 20mA.

> Low-level Output VOL on HVOUT max 3V for IOUT = 1 mA

When the output is low, the driver's strength is much lower. It is only able to sink 1mA with a voltage drop of 3V. It can't drive LEDs in this mode.

In other words, the output can source 25mA and sink 1mA current, it is asymmetrical, so you should put the LEDs between output and ground.

Comment: So the 78V would be from output pin to GND?

Comment: Yes, with a 25mA load.